# Extending asyncs race function that only takes two inputs to multiple inputs?

Tags: haskell, asynchronous

I'm trying to extend asyncs `race` function such that it could be applied to every IO function in a list but I'm having trouble in reasoning out the extension.

My first approach was to split the list in half and zip it together such that each entry is a distinct couple. Once that is done map race across the list and return a random entry as the defacto fastest. The issue with this approach was that I ran into the following error that I couldn't find a solution to mitigate :

```
No instance for (Show (IO Int)) arising from a use of ‘print’
```

After a few hours of trying to find a solution I then looked to how the function worked in of itself. I realised that it worked much like the `max` operator in that it has to be nested.

```
race a1 (race a2 a3)
= {Apply race, race a2 a3 := alpha}
race a1 alpha
= {Apply race}
alpha'
```

I think that this could be a better approach but what I'm unsure about is race's behaviour itself. If I apply the inner race in the example then that returns the evaluation of that race comparison not the function so then in the outer race, what's actually occurring is applying race to a function and an evaluated function.

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like this should be fine if you don't care which action it was that gave the answer first:

```
raceAll :: [IO a] -> IO a
raceAll [] = fail "whoops"
raceAll acts = go acts where
    go [io] = io
    go ios = go (raceAdjacent ios)
    raceAdjacent (io:io':ios) = (either id id <$> race io io') : raceAdjacent ios
    raceAdjacent short = short
```

This makes a binary tree of races, with the original actions at the leaves. `raceAdjacent` pairs up adjacent list elements; like this:

```
[x0, x1, x2, x3, x4, ...
           |
           v
[race x0 x1, race x2 x3, race x4 x5, ...
```

This cuts the length of the list in half, and then `go` just iterates that process until you only have one thing left that's a race between all the original actions.

If you do want to know which action finished first, you can zip the actions up with their index before racing them:

```
raceAllIndexed :: [IO a] -> IO (Int, a)
raceAllIndexed acts = raceAll (zipWith (\n io -> (,) n <$> io) [0..] acts)
```

You can try it out in ghci:

```
> raceAllIndexed [threadDelay ((n*(-1000000)) `mod` 3333333) | n <- [1..10]]
(2,())
```

Comment: Thank you very much but I'm having a little trouble in understanding the first block! I can follow your block until the raceAdjacent lines, would you be able to explain them please?

Comment: @JiangShi I have added some text; does that help?

Comment: That's a perfect explanation! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

"async" provides a [`Concurrently`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/async-2.2.3/docs/Control-Concurrent-Async.html#t:Concurrently) newtype over `IO`.

`Concurrently` has an [`Alternative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Alternative) instance, where [`<|>`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--124--62-) races one action against another.

We can combine this with the [`asum`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:asum) function from [`Data.Foldable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html), in order to define `raceAll`:

```
raceAll :: [IO a] -> IO a
raceAll = runConcurrently . asum . map Concurrently
```

Notice that this version `raceAll` will wait forever for the empty list, because that's what [`empty`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:empty) for `Concurrently` does.

---

Just for fun, a quirkier way of defining the function would be:

```
import Data.Foldable
import Data.Monoid (Alt(..))
import Data.Coerce (coerce)
import Control.Concurrent.Async

raceAll :: [IO a] -> IO a 
raceAll xs = 
    let Alt (Concurrently x) = foldMap coerce xs
     in x
```