# Executing a function randomly of a list of functions

Tags: haskell

=== Evaluation of HStatement (bar if and selection) ===

```
evalStatement_ :: Env -> HStatement -> IOThrowsError ()
evalStatement_ env (Do cond expr) = evalVal env cond >>= \x -> case x of
                                                                 HBool False -> return ()
                                                                  HBool True  -> do
                                                                          traverse_ (evalStatement_ env) expr
                                                                          evalStatement_ env (Do cond expr)

evalStatement_ env (Skip skip) = return ()
evalStatement_ env (Print (HString val)) = getVar env val >>= \x -> liftIO $ putStrLn $ show x
evalStatement_ env (Print val) = evalVal env val >>= \x -> liftIO $ putStrLn $ show x
evalStatement_ env (Eval val) = do
     result <- evalVal env val
     return ()
```

=== Representation of Selection & If ===

```
parseIf :: Parser HStatement
parseIf = do
         string "("
         cond  <- parseArith
         string ")->"
         spaces
         expr  <- many1 $ parseStatements
         spaces
         return $ If (cond, expr)
parseSelection :: Parser HStatement
parseSelection = do
            _ <- string "if"
            spaces
            selection <- many1 $ parseIf
            spaces
            _ <- string "fi"
            spaces
            return $ Selection selection
```

N.B : If evaluation of selection is changed to the below, then the program runs and terminates and does give output:

```
evalStatement_ env (Selection if_ selection fi_ n) = evalStatement_ env (selection !! randIdx n) >>= \res -> if res == ()
                                                                                                                then return ()
                                                                                                                 else return ()
```

The output however gives varying amounts of the even integers between 1 and 10. For example one output would print all even integers and another prints on the number 6.

tldr; is there a way to execute a random function from a list of functions randomly and if the result is not ideal, reexecute the function to execute a random function until the result is idea?

I'm trying to write a function which executes a random entry in a list of functions. Each entry in the list is constructed in the following way: `If (HVal, HStatement) -- If (Guard,Statement)`  where

```
HVal:
data HVal
= HInteger Integer
HBool    Bool
HString  String
HList    [HVal]
Length   HVal
Arith    HVal Op HVal
Assign   String HVal
deriving (Eq, Read)

HStatement:
data HStatement
=  Eval   HVal
|  Print  HVal
|  Do     HVal [HStatement]
|  If     (HVal, [HStatement])
|  Selection [HStatement] 
deriving (Eq, Read)
```

What I tried so far was using `Asyncs race` function as per my [question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66590642/extending-asyncs-race-function-that-only-takes-two-inputs-to-multiple-inputs). My thinking behind this was if there exists a list of n entries in a list that are constructed as `If (HVal, HStatement)`, then running a `race` function over a list that only contain a list of HStatements whose guards were evaluated to true would return the function that executes the fastest of the true guards.

Trying to incorporate this `raceAll` behaviour into my code base proved to be too difficult to me due to the constraint of `IO`. I redid the approach by considering using a random number generator.

So now I'm generating a random index of the list of guard statements pairs. I execute the entry in this list and perform a case analysis. If the output is `()` then I call the function again otherwise I return the output. To do this I'm using two functions wherein `selection` represents a list of `if's`:

```
evalStatement_ env (If (cond, expr)) = evalVal env cond >>= \x -> case x of
                                                                      HBool False -> return ()
                                                                      HBool True  -> traverse_ (evalStatement_ env) expr
evalStatement_ env (Selection selection) = evalStatement_ env (selection !! randIdx 1) >>= \res -> case res of -- randIdx produces an index between 0 and 1 representing the two branches in the selection block that could be taken
                                                                                                                () -> evalStatement_ env (Selection selection)
                                                                                                                _  -> return $ res

randIdx n = unsafePerformIO (getStdRandom (randomR (0, n - 1)))
```

Take the following program as example:

```
f := [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]
n := 0
N := len(f)

Do (n < N)->

        a := f.n

        if ((a % 2) = 0)-> print(a)
           ((a % 1) = 1)-> print(a)
        fi

        n := n + 1

Od
```

What occurs here is that the program gives no output at all and doesn't terminate. What I would have expected to happen was that a random index is generated between 0 and the number of possible branches minus one. Then this would have been evaluated and if it returned a value, this would have been taken otherwise if it was the unit type, a new random index would have been generated and that would have been used.

I can execute the program however if the function definition for selection is `traverse_ (evalStatement_ env) selection` but I'm just unsure on how to achieve this pseudo randomness. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It looks to me like `randIdx 1` will always yield `0`, making the rest of the program rather uninteresting.

Comment: @amalloy It doesn't work even when the number yielded is greater than zero

Comment: If `randIdx` is changed to `unsafePerformIO (getStdRandom (randomR (0, n )))`, the program terminates with the error : `Lang: Prelude.!!: index too large `

Comment: Yikes. 1. The argument to `randIdx` should almost certainly be some computation involving `length selection`. 2. Don't use `unsafePerformIO` for this. Instead add a monadic effect that's suitable for generating randomness to your evaluation stack. `IO` would be one choice; [`RandT StdGen`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.5.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Random-Lazy.html) would be another.

Comment: @DanielWagner I was just using `unsafePerformIO` to just get the function up quickly! I was planning to change it once I got what I wanted working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say,

> If the output is `()` then I call the function again otherwise I return the output.

This is a strange thing to say, because there is no "otherwise" -- if your thing returns `()` sometimes, it can never return anything but `()`, because there is no other value with the same type! In particular, this means it is impossible to reach the `_` branch of your case.

In your language as shown here, statements fundamentally do not compute data. Perhaps you should change your `Selection` constructor to take an `[(HVal, HStatement)]` instead of an `[HStatement]` (representing pairs of the computation that returns something interesting that you can `case` on together with the statement to execute in some appropriate branch of that `case`), or modify the type that statements compute to something richer than `()`.

Comment: I'm really sorry! I can see how I made a mistake in describing the problem now. I will amend my post now to include the function definitions. I think that I might have to evaluate the guard bounded to the statement rather than the entire HStatement itself because all evaluations of `HStatement`s produce `()`. On representing Selection however, that's kind of how I'm doing it already in that `Selection [HStatement]` == `Selection [If (HVal, HStatement)]`

Comment: @JiangShi Is `parseSelection` the only parser that calls `parseIf`? If so, I'm going to double down on my claim: not only should `Selection` take an `[(HVal, HStatement)]`, the `If` constructor for statements should not exist. This is because `If` is only allowed inside a selection and it is the only thing allowed inside a selection -- so it doesn't make sense to split it out as a separate entity. (If `parseIf` is called by other parsers than `parseSelection`, I would retract the "`If` constructor should not exist" but not the proposed change to `Selection`.)

Comment: Yeah `parseSelection` is the only parser that calls it! See the reason why I had them split to begin with was because I couldn't parse selection correctly without the sub parse of `if` which is why my selection is built up of many `ifs`. Why is this added complexity bad?

Comment: @JiangShi 1. I don't see why having a sub-parser requires adding a constructor to `HStatement`. For example, you call the `spaces` subparser, but have no corresponding constructor. Perhaps this would be a good fresh question to ask? 2. The added complexity is bad because it introduces unnecessary failure points: it is possible for buggy Haskell code to construct selections that contain non-`If` statements (buggy construction) and it is not possible for the compiler to see that matches that only consider `If` are complete (buggy consumption).

Comment: Ah I see that makes a lot sense thank you. I know its asking for a lot but would you be able to guide me on the question I asked or will the answer to this become more apparent once I amend `Selection` ?

Comment: @JiangShi That is another benefit of fixing `Selection`, yes -- I suspect the answer will indeed become glaringly obvious. ^_^

Comment: Guess its time to bang my head against a wall for a different reason now! XD Thank you!